# Passing in Gem Version Not Working Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, solr, sunspot

I am trying to install Sunspot for a full text search of my rails app.

When passing in gems and specific versions to the gem file

```
gem 'sunspot_rails', '~> 2.1.0'
gem 'sunspot_solr', '~> 2.1.0'
```

it ignores the version and installs 2.1.1 - I have also tried manually installing them from the command prompt

```
gem install sunspot_rails -v "~> 2.1.0"
```

but the same thing happens.

Any help as to why this is happening would be greatly appreciated. Any questions please ask. And yes I am still a rails beginner. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because of the `~>` before the version number. It will install any versions from 2.1.0 to 2.2 (exclusive).

If you want to install exactly the version 2.1.0, remove `~>`:

```
gem 'sunspot_rails', '2.1.0'
gem 'sunspot_solr', '2.1.0'
```

Some examples on dependency specifiers:

```
Specification From  ... To (exclusive)
">= 3.0"      3.0   ... &infin;
"~> 3.0"      3.0   ... 4.0
"~> 3.0.0"    3.0.0 ... 3.1
"~> 3.5"      3.5   ... 4.0
"~> 3.5.0"    3.5.0 ... 3.6
"~> 3"        3.0   ... 4.0
```

Check this [doc](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Version.html) for more details.